# ¿Cómo paso un objeto por parámetro en JAVA sin modificarlo?

Tags: java

Tengo una clase **MEDALLA** que contiene dos atributos. 
Tipo = Cadena, Num = Entero.
Y una clase **Atleta** que contiene un objeto de tipo MEDALLA. Estoy usando varios objetos Atleta, y necesito que cada uno tenga una copia de un objeto MEDALLA, va más o menos así.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    class MEDALLA {
        String Tipo = "";
        int Num = 0;

       void New(){
           System.out.println("Tipo :");
           Tipo = input.nextLine();
         }
    }

    class Atleta {
        String Nombre = "";
        MEDALLA M;

        void Registrar (MEDALLA IN){
            Nombre = input.nextLine();
           M = IN; //Aquí sólo quiero hacer una copia de un objeto medalla.
        }

       void Ganar(){
                M.Num++;
             }
    }

   //Inicio
   MEDALLA MEDAL = new MEDALLA();
   MEDAL.New();
   Atleta At1, At2 = new Atleta();
   At1.INI(MEDAL);
   At2.INI(MEDAL);
   At1.Ganar() //En este punto, también modifica  a At2.
```

**¿Qué puedo hacer para crear una copia del objeto MEDAL independiente para objeto Atleta?**

Answer (score 3):

Puedes hacer un metodo clone en la clase `Medalla`:

```
public Medalla getClone() {
    return new Medalla(tipo, num);
}

MEDALLA MEDAL = new MEDALLA();
MEDAL.New();
Atleta At1, At2 = new Atleta();
At1.INI(MEDAL.getClone());
At2.INI(MEDAL.getClone());
At1.Ganar();
```

Así debería funcionar. Pero el problema que expones está mal modelado ya que no haces uso del paradigma orientado a objetos, que es el que usa Java, ni de su convención de nombres en variables y clases. De la siguiente forma estaría bien modelado:

Clase `Medalla`

```
public class Medalla {
    private String tipo;

    public Medalla(String tipo) {
        this.tipo = tipo;
    }

    public String getTipo() {
        return tipo;
    }
}
```

Clase `Atleta`

```
public class Atleta {
    private String nombre;
    private Medalla medalla;
    private int num;

    public Atleta(String nombre, Medalla medalla, int num) {
        this.nombre = nombre;
        this.medalla = medalla;
        this.num = num;
    }

    public Atleta(String nombre, Medalla medalla) {
        this.nombre = nombre;
        this.medalla = medalla;
        this.num = 0;
    }

    public String getNombre() {
        return nombre;
    }

    public Medalla getMedalla() {
        return medalla;
    }

    public int getNum() {
        return num;
    }

    public void ganar() {
        num++;
    }
}
```

Clase `Main`

```
public class Main {

    private static Scanner input;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        input = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.print("Tipo: ");
        Medalla medalla = new Medalla(input.nextLine());

        Atleta at1 = new Atleta("at1", medalla);
        Atleta at2 = new Atleta("at2", medalla);

        at1.ganar();
        System.out.println(at1.getNombre() + ": " + at1.getNum());
        System.out.println(at2.getNombre() + ": " + at2.getNum());
    }

}
```

Comment: Intenté hacer un método para clonar, pero mi clase es un TDA lista y me da error de memoria en la ejecución.

Comment: Si me das un poco mas de información puedo intentar ayudarte, de todas formas con lo que te puse debería funcionar.

Answer (score 1):

La verdad es que no entiendo mucho lo que quieres hacer, en donde llamas al método registrar( MEDALLA in )?

Por qué crear el método new(), no es más fácil meter lo que hay dentro en el constructor?

Tampoco entiendo lo que quieres decir con :

```
At1.Ganar() //En este punto, también modifica  a At2.
```

Sólo se deberia modificar el objeto At1, y otra cosa es como sumas **num** desde la clase Atleta si la has declarado en la clase Medalla.

Espero haberte ayudado en algo.
Un saludo

Comment: Esa es una versión súper sencilla de mi programa, cuando uso At1.Ganar() también modifica al atributo M de At2, quiero evitar eso.

Comment: Intenta no instanciar así: Atleta At1, At2 = new Atleta();

Comment: Instancia Atleta At1 = new Atleta(); y por otro lado Atleta At2 = new Atleta();